# a user defined class of ARRAY in c++ with pointer

Tags: c++, class, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

This code is a class of  arrays definition that uses dynamic memory to allocate memory. The command `ArrayClass temp(_size);` in operator+ method gives the following runtime error.

> Unhandled exception at 0x7715C54F in ArrayClass.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: std::bad_array_new_length at memory location 0x0033FB10.

If we convert this command to `ArrayClass *temp = new ArrayClass(_size)`, no error will be occured. But the new object `temp`  that was allocated by `new` operator will not be deleted.
Does anyone have a solution?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class ArrayClass {
private:
    int _size;
    float* _ar;
public:
    ArrayClass(const int& size) {
        _size = size;
        _ar = new float[_size];
    }

    ~ArrayClass() {
        delete[]_ar;
    }

    const ArrayClass& operator=(const ArrayClass& RightOperand) {
        if (this != &RightOperand) {
            if (this->_size != RightOperand._size) {
                delete[] this->_ar;
                this->_size = RightOperand._size;
                this->_ar = new float[this->_size];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < RightOperand._size; i++)
            {
                this->_ar[i] = RightOperand._ar[i];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    const ArrayClass& operator+(const ArrayClass& RightOperand) {
        //*this+RightOperand
        if (this->_size != RightOperand._size) {
            cout << "different Size";
            exit(1);
        }

        ArrayClass temp(_size);
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        {
            temp._ar[i] = this->_ar[i] + RightOperand._ar[i];
        }
        return temp;
    }
};


int main() {
    ArrayClass  x(5), y(5), z(5);
        
    x = y;

    z= x + y;

    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is immediately obvious that [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) is not observed, although it might not be the only problem with code and not immediate reason for the crash.

Comment: You can't return a reference to a local variable.

Comment: Tnx a lot for your solutions